# C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Tags: c++, qt

Following bit of code is throwing error. I have no idea why. Can anyone shed some light?
All codes are on different files.

```
#ifndef MAINSESSION_H
#define MAINSESSION_H
#include "sessionsuper.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
class MainSession : public SessionSuper
{
public:
    MainSession();
private:

};

#include "mainsession.h"

MainSession::MainSession()
{

}

#endif // MAINSESSION_H
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "mainsession.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MainSession *ms;   //Error here
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ms=new MainSession(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
#ifndef SESSIONSUPER_H
#define SESSIONSUPER_H

class SessionSuper
{
public:
    SessionSuper();
};

#endif // SESSIONSUPER_H
#include "sessionsuper.h"

SessionSuper::SessionSuper()
{
}
```

Error:

> d:\qtsrc\untitled4\mainwindow.h:20: error: C2143: syntax error :
>   missing ';' before '*'
>
> d:\qtsrc\untitled4\mainwindow.h:20: error: C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   d:\qtsrc\untitled4\mainwindow.h:20: error: C4430: missing type
>   specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Am using Qt+msvc10.0 compiler.

Update:-

```
#ifndef MAINSESSION_H
#define MAINSESSION_H
#include "sessionsuper.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
class MainSession : public SessionSuper
{
public:
    MainSession(MainWindow*);
private:
MainWindow *mw;
};

#endif // MAINSESSION_H
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include "mainsession.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MainSession *ms;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
#ifndef SESSIONSUPER_H
#define SESSIONSUPER_H

class SessionSuper
{
public:
    SessionSuper();
};

#endif // SESSIONSUPER_H
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
#include "mainsession.h"

MainSession::MainSession(MainWindow mss)
{
  mw=mss;

}
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //ms=new MainSession(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
#include "sessionsuper.h"

SessionSuper::SessionSuper()
{
}
```

Errors:- a lot more but of same type

Comment: Show the contents of `mainwindow.h`.

Comment: the code you shows includes mainsessio.h from within mainsession.h?? Please edit the post to make moer sense

Comment: All are different files.

Comment: Do not add `solved` text to the question. Mark your answer accepted instead (you may need to wait some time to do this). Putting the corrected code in your answer will certainly make it more helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Is Solved by using the observer Model.

A Complete Demo [Here](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/avoiding-circular-dependencies-using-observer-patterns/)

Add a Comment If you want the working  code of the above code.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 5):

You have circular include, forward declaration MainSession type to break the current circula include issue.

In MainWindow.h

```
//#include "mainsession.h" comment out this line

class MainSession;     // add forward declaration
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    //...
    MainSession *ms; //Error here.
};
```

Comment: But what happens if i want pass a object of mainwindow (this) into mainsession?what do i do then?

Comment: pass by reference or pointer - still doesn't need a complete type.

Comment: How do i do this code?
`#ifndef MAINSESSION_H
#define MAINSESSION_H
#include "sessionsuper.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
class MainSession : public SessionSuper
{
public:
    MainSession(MainWindow*);
private:
MainWindow *mw;
};

#endif // MAINSESSION_H

#include "mainsession.h"

MainSession::MainSession(MainWindow mss)
{
  mw=mss;

}

`

Comment: Problem Is Solved by using the observer Model.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code like this:

```
class MainWindow
{
public:
    explicit MainWindow();
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MainSession *ms;   //My error also here <- see this
};
```

See here in my code where `MainSession` is missing and I got same error in the line. Hope it will help. `MainSession` definition may missing because of file missing, file not included, scope problem (another namespace) etc. Please check these. `namespace Ui` (different) probably the problem.